# Schedule quarterly code run - PHP

Tags: php, schedule

I have a PHP website running on windows server (no Cron stuff allowed :)), how can I schedule a PHP code (sending emails) to run every quarter (every 3 months) ? I found ways to utilize Windows Task Scheduler , but in the scheduling triggering options, there is no *Quarterly* option. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think he means 15 minutes.

Comment: If you mean every 15 minutes, why not schedule four tasks: at '00, '15, '30 and '45 that are repeated every hour.

Comment: and you couldn't simply check the date on a more frequent schedule and run code if it is a new quarter?

Comment: "*Quarterly*" tends to mean every three month @Jerodev

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`schtasks`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_minutes) to run the code every `15` minutes:

```
schtasks /create /tr 'php foo.php' /sc minute /mo 15
```

Where you replace `foo.php` with the actual `php` script.

If the script should be scheduled every three months (quarterly), use the following command:

```
schtasks /create /tr 'php foo.php' /sc monthly /mo 3
```

Comment: The OP said "*Quarterly*" which typically means every three months.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: well that's only modifying a few parameters. Both options now available...

Comment: @JayBlanchard is right, I meant every 3 months.. thanks to all.. I will give it a try and see how it goes.